# triangle construction given side, angle and median

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

I can't figure out the solution to this, it looks to me like it doesn't have any solution but I need some proof.

problem: Construct a triangle ABC with given $a=6 cm$ $\alpha=75^\circ $ and $m_{a}=4cm$.

Comment: what is $a$(okay one side). What is $\alpha$(yes angle but which one, you already specified a side), $m_a$(median from a?)

Comment: a is the side opposite to the angle alpha and ma is median from a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find *any* point $P$ such that $\angle BPC = 75^\circ$ (see below), and consider the circumcircle $\bigcirc BPC$. By the Inscribed Angle Theorem, *every* point $Q$ on $\stackrel{\frown}{BPC}$ of that circle is such that $\angle BQC = 75^\circ$. Vertex $A$ is one of those points. Vertex $A$ is also $m_a$ units from the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. Thus, $A$ is one of the points of intersection ---if any--- of $\stackrel{\frown}{BPC}$ with the circle of radius $m_a$ about that midpoint.

---

How do you find that first point, $P$? One way is to erect a perpendicular to $\overline{BC}$ at $B$, as well as a ray making an angle of $15^\circ$ (the complement of $75^\circ$) with $\overline{BC}$ at $C$; where these lines meet is $P$. (Why?) Constructing the perpendicular is easy; for the other ray, it helps to realize that $60^\circ = 4\cdot 15^\circ$.

Comment: People proved this particular one cannot be done. But I'm gonna ignore and pretend it could be done for simplicity of the explanation. Draw two intercepting lines, r and s, at a point P and an angle of 75 degrees. Draw a paralel line to one of the lines you draw, say r, such that its distance to r is 6cm. Let this paralel intercept s at point C, point B is in r and in the perpendicular to r through C.

Answer (score 0):

Apollonius's theorem says that, $4m_a^2=2 b^2 + 2 c^2 - a^2$. Hence, $b^2+c^2=(64+36)/2=50$.

Now by the cosine rule, $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\alpha$. So, $7=bc\cos 75^{\circ}$. Thus we have $bc$ and $b^2+c^2$. But since, $(b-c)^2=b^2+c^2-2bc=50-\frac{14}{\cos 75^{\circ}}<0$, $b-c$ isn't real and hence the construction isn't possible.

Comment: How to construct it (without computing anything)?

Comment: I see but that is actually what I need to do.

Comment: @Serillan Ok :)

Comment: @Sawarnik: Actually, if you solve the quadratic, you find that there are no real solutions. (Likewise, if you perform the construction in my answer, the circles fail to intersect.) So, the construction *isn't* possible.

Comment: @Blue Oh I see, how silly of me! There are no solutions, I ll update the answer.

Comment: @Serillan Just pinging you to tell that as Blue pointed out, as there are no solutions of the quadratic, and hence the construction is **not** possible. How silly of me!